# Clean-up needed: [identity]

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

I draw your attention to the [identity](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity) tag.

There is no tag wiki, and no usage guidance, of course.

Questions are quite scattered.

- How to delete a Twitter account
- How to create a "new online identity" (closed)
- A web app request for managing muliple online identities (closed)
- An overly broad question on how to report sites that leak a person's name
- Identity theft on Facebook, resulting in lots of email notifications of Friend Requests
- Identity theft on Facebook, with a "duplicate" account
- Whether a personal GitHub account should be used at work (closed)
- A rather unclear question about Facebook Safety Check interacting with Facebook's "Checkpoint" (probably will be closed)

It seems clear to me that this tag serves no useful purpose and should be cleaned up. Any counter-arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [identity](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity) questions re-tagged.